# Cannot receive mail on Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: email

I have a home server running on Ubuntu Server 18.04. There are several devices in my home network. But my router is configured to redirect the incoming traffic on the ports 80 and 25 to the server (TCP). HTTP website on the port 80 works perfectly and is available from the Internet. But I don't receive any mail at all.

Assume I have a user called *username* and the hostname of the server is *example.com* (in /etc/hostname). I have an A record for *example.com* pointing to my router's global IP. I don't have any MX records for *example.com* but [this](https://serverfault.com/a/470651/433850) post says that it defaults to the A record in that case.

I have tried installing [sendmail](https://tecadmin.net/install-sendmail-on-ubuntu/) and [postfix](https://www.tecmint.com/setup-postfix-mail-server-in-ubuntu-debian/) from the tutorials. But I still don't receive any mail at all. The file /var/mail/username exists but has a zero size.

Note that other users on the server do receive some local system mail (cron, etc.). But no mail from the Internet. I need to be able to receive mail for *username@example.com* address.

Am I missing something? This drives me crazy.

Comment: Are you sure you're connectable from the outside? Have you verified this? I've seen ISPs drop **all** traffic to and from port 25, except their own SMTP servers, to avoid spam. It should additionally be noted that running e-mail at home is difficult, as many blacklists contain the customer addresses of ISPs.

Comment: How do I verify this? Any console command?

Comment: You can't verify it from your local system. You need to verify it from some other place external to your ISPs network. This can for instance be a laptop connected to 4G or similar. Run `nc hostname 25` and see if you get any response. The mailserver should print a header upon connecting.

Comment: I just checked and received a response. Something like `220 hostname ESMTP Sendmail 8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-10; Sat, 28 Dec 2019 21:23:21 GMT; (No UCE/UBE) logging access from: ... [...my IP...]`

Comment: That indicates that the port is indeed open. What shows up in your logs when you attempt to send an e-mail to a user on the system from some external site (e.g. gmail)? Can you include your configfiles?

Comment: Logs on the server? Where are they located?

Comment: `/var/log/mail.log`. Also add your configuration files to the question.

Comment: Also, I removed the `sendmail` package and installed `postfix`. Why did the response say `ESMTP Sendmail`?

Comment: Probably because sendmail is still running, for some reason. Postfix will say postfix.

Answer (score 0):

Amazing, but it turns out I just had to reboot the system. I uninstalled `sendmail` but it was still running in RAM, interfering with `postfix` (which I had installed using [this](https://www.tecmint.com/setup-postfix-mail-server-in-ubuntu-debian/) tutorial). After reboot `postfix` started receiving all emails normally.